# MSMQ Complex Object Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: c#, msmq

I am attempting to send a message to MSMQ utilizing the XmlFormatter for an object that contains a property of type object. If the object property is left null, the serialization/deserialization works flawlessly. However, if I assign an object I receive an exception when invoking .send. There was an error generating the XML document is the only information that I receive. Both classes are marked serializable. Is there something else that I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your objects are not properly serialized into XML.

how does it work for example if you simply assign a string value to the object property?

You can use a small console app or the debugger to test how your classes are serialized and deserialized to/from xml and check the behavior of the XmlFormatter.

Comment: I can serialize / deserialize without any issues if the queue is out of the equation. So, I'm not sure what is going wrong. All of the classes involved are serializable. How can I verify the XmlFormatter behavior? I just used a NetDataContractSerializer utility class that we have to serialize and deserialize to make sure the objects were structured correctly.

Comment: The MessageQueue.Formatter.Write fails with the same error. Obviously, this is what MessageQueue.Send is performing under the hood so this is no surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your complex class declares a property as type object, when something is assigned to it, serialization sees the property as an object of the type assigned.

For example, if you assign your object property a value of new CustomClass(), serialization will expect an object(), but find a CustomClass(), so serialization will fail. (Type CustomClasss was not expected)

If you assign your object property a value of new object(), I suspect the serialization will then work.